# Difference between vmk_NmpPathGroupState vmk_NmpPathGetPathGroupState and vmk_NmpPathGroupState vmk_NmpPathGroupGetState

Tags: vmware

Can somebody please explain the difference between vmk_NmpPathGroupState vmk_NmpPathGetPathGroupState (vmk_ScsiPath *p) Returns Path Group state of the given path and vmk_NmpPathGroupState vmk_NmpPathGroupGetState (vmk_NmpPathGroup *pg) Returns the state associated with a given path group.

Confused between the two, I am asking this wrt MPIO in my mind. Please give some examples.

Comment: Read the documentation or ask VMware. I doubt you will get an answer here.

Comment: I read it. Its very fuzzy there. Okay I will try to look some more.